# Using rstrui.exe inside the "Repair Your Computer" Advanced Boot Option

Tags: windows-7, system-restore

When you press <kbd>F8</kbd> to use the "Repair Your Computer" Advanced Boot Option, and then want to run `rstrui.exe` to do a system restore...

Does running `rstrui.exe` (System Restore) this way cause the system restore points to disappear?

If so, how can I make them reappear so that I can restore the restore point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't. It will load the remote system, then run System Recovery

Comment: Yup, we booted it up in safe mode and there just weren't any restore points.  Somebody has to tell them end users to create those once in a while, it can SYA in the end.

Comment: I find most users simply disable it, not realizing windows 7 restore is much better then XP's restore function